Is it possible to resize image of child element without affecting parent element in React using Tailwind CSS
I have a Products page that renders all my SingleProduct components.
This is working ok but I would like to resize the image on my SingleProduct page but when i do it also resizes all my products on my Products page.
Is it possible to apply different css styles to these components considering how I am rendering them?
const Products = () => {
    const products = data;

    return (
        <div className='pt-12 grid gap-4 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 '>
            {products.map((prod) => {
                return (
                    <Link to={`/product/${prod.id}`}>
                        <SingleProduct product={prod}></SingleProduct>
                    </Link>
                )
            })}
            <Link to='/home'></Link>
        </div>


    )
}

export default Products

const SingleProduct = (props) => {
    const [image, setImage] = useState()
    const [title, setTitle] = useState()
    const [price, setPrice] = useState()
    useEffect(() => {
        setImage(props.product.image)
        setTitle(props.product.title)
        setPrice(props.product.price)
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="text-center font-bold text-lg ">
                <h2 className='capitalize tracking-wider'>{title}</h2>
            </div>

            <figure className='px-8 pt-8'>
                <img style={{ width: '70%' }}
                    src={image}
                    alt='Elf'
                    className='rounded-xl w-full object-cover'
                />
            <div className='card-body items-center text-center'>
                <h2 className='card-title capitalize tracking-wider'>Price: {price}</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SingleProduct


import SingleProduct from "./SingleProduct";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import data from "../data";

const SingleProductPage = () => {
  let { id } = useParams();
  const [product, setProduct] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    id && setProduct(data.find((prod) => prod.id == id))
  }, [id]) // runs whenever the id changed and updates the product

  return product ? <SingleProduct product={product} /> : null
}

export default SingleProductPage;

import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom'
import { HomeLayout, Landing, Products, SingleProduct } from './pages'
import './App.css'

import SingleProductPage from './pages/SingleProductPage'


const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <HomeLayout></HomeLayout>,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <Landing></Landing>,
      },
      {
        path: 'product',
        element: <Products></Products>,
      },
      {
        path: 'product/:id',
        element: <SingleProductPage></SingleProductPage>,
      },
    ]
  },

])

function App() {

  return (
    <RouterProvider router={router}></RouterProvider>
  )
}

export default App


"I would like to resize the image on my SingleProduct page but when i do it also resizes all my products on my Products page." - Well, it appears that the Products page component is rendering the SingleProduct component that renders the images you are styling, so this seems to be expected behavior. I don't understand what the issue/question is then why you would expect anything different. Can you [edit] to clarify the problem?

I'm trying to resize the image in SingleProduct page without affecting all the images on Products page. I'm assuming this is not possible since products is rendering SingleProduct? I thought it might be possible to override the CSS in Products page somehow and fix the images

What is the Single Product page? Is it also rendering the same SingleProduct component? You can certainly scope CSS rules by placing them into containers or div element and giving them different id or class attributes and setting your CSS rules accordingly. Can you [edit] to include a complete and relevant [mcve] of the code you are working with?

Yes it is also rendering SingleProduct edited to add it to original post. Don't think I can scope any CSS rules on Projects component as it only rendering SingleProject component.

Added App.jsx to show how app is routed

You can scope CSS rules by placing them into containers or div elements and giving them different id or class attributes and setting your CSS rules accordingly.
Example:
CSS
.product-image {
  width: 70%;
}

#products-page {
  .product-image {
    width: 100px;
  }
}

#product-page {
  .product-image {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
  }
}

const Products = () => {
  return (
    <div
      id="products-page" // <-- container id
      className="pt-12 grid gap-4 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 "
    >
      {products.map((prod) => {
        return (
          <Link key={prod.id} to={`/product/${prod.id}`}>
            <SingleProduct product={prod} />
          </Link>
        );
      })}
      <Link to="/home"></Link>
    </div>
  );
};

const SingleProductPage = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const product = products.find((prod) => prod.id === id);

  return (
    <div
      id="product-page" // <-- container id
    >
      {product && <SingleProduct product={product} />}
    </div>
  );
};

const SingleProduct = ({ product }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="text-center font-bold text-lg ">
        <h2 className="capitalize tracking-wider">{product.title}</h2>
      </div>

      <figure className="px-8 pt-8">
        <img
          src={product.image}
          alt="Elf"
          className="product-image" // <-- image class
        />
      </figure>
      <div className="card-body items-center text-center">
        <h2 className="card-title capitalize tracking-wider">
          Price: {product.price}
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};




Container
Layout




"products-page"



"product-page"




